# Dockerfile - setting ENV variable from output of .sh script

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am working to "dockerize" a build process and one of the things I need to figure out is how to set an ENV variable based on the output of a script. Essentially all the script does is check for branch name - `if master return foo, else return bar` sort of thing.

I have tried a couple of things: export - which I know does not stick, I need an variable that persists. I have tried something like this: `RUN MY_VAR=$(/path/to/my/script/script.sh)` with no success.

This needs to happen during the build stage, not after it the image has been built. These ENV variables need to be set for when the docker image is run.

Thanks for any assistance that you may be able to offer.

Comment: Is this script independent? Or does it need to be run from inside Dockerfile?

Comment: It needs to be run from within the dockerfile. Essentially the reason for this is I want to have the image and the proper env variables setup. The way this project was developed is that if `branch=master` setup variables this way, if `branch=anything else` then setup the variables another way. and these scripts were written for this exact purpose. I was trying to avoid doing the passing in of the variables when the image is being run. and I may not be able to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Directly for your question, there is some kind of workaround.
You can save output of your script anywhere at the filesystem like

`RUN /path/to/my/script/script.sh > /opt/myvalue`

And in entrypoint or cmd script use like this

`export MY_VAR=$(echo /opt/myvalue)`

But If you provide more detail why you use script like this and for what need this variable, maybe there will more good solution

Comment: So what I ended up doing was something similar:

`RUN script that gets latest.sh > /tmp/LATEST_VERSION`

`RUN LATEST_VERSION=$(cat /tmp/LATEST_VERSION); run my other process that is dependent on this variable.sh && do this other thing with that variable.sh`

So far it seems to work, just thought there was a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: I think more elegant way would be use —build-arg and ARG notation. Set this variable during the build with output of your script and then set it with ENV to permanent usage like describe in this article   https://vsupalov.com/docker-build-pass-environment-variables/

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at that. I like the way that looks. Appreciate it!